# mach-o linker error with Facebook ios sdk 3.7 when used in static lib

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm using Facebook SDK 3.7 in an iOS static library project isolating core functionality for various apps.  It's a nice improvement in the SDK that you no longer have to manually include dependent frameworks.  However, the end project that uses the static lib throws Mach-O linker errors when building.  Manually adding the frameworks from this link (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/upgrading-from-3.5-to-3.6/) fixes it.

Is there some change that can be made (to their build scripts, to project settings?) to avoid needing to do this in this scenario?

### Linker Errors

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "_ACFacebookAppIdKey", referenced from: 
-[FBSystemAccountStoreAdapter requestAccessToFacebookAccountStore:defaultAudience:isReauthorize:appID:session:‌​handler:] 
in FacebookSDK(FBSystemAccountStoreAdapter.o) "_ACFacebookAudienceEveryone", referenced from:" ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You still need to link against the `Accounts.framework`:

[image: Adding accounts.framework, iOS 7]

Comment: Right, as noted I needed to link against each of the 5 frameworks listed at the link, including Accounts.  What I'm looking for though is a solution avoiding this manual linking, which should be no longer necessary since SDK 3.6

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood, if the SDK requires the Accounts.framework then need to link it. You can just use the built in Facebook APIs but that too will require linking the Accounts.framework.

Comment: Please check out the [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/upgrading-from-3.5-to-3.6/) I included in the question.  The SDK from 3.6 on no longer requires the Accounts.framework as it dynamically loads it.  So in my static library, I don't link to it or any other Apple framework, and things work fine.  However, when using my static lib in another project, I now need to link to the frameworks.  I'm looking for a workaround for that.